# Haskell: Making Quasi-Quoted values strict / evaluated at compile-time

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, template-haskell, quasiquotes

I have a 'Month' type, which is roughly

```
newtype Month = Month Word8
```

where the `Month` constructor isn't exported; instead, a function

```
mon :: Word8 -> Maybe Month
mon i = if i > 0 && i < 13
        then Just $ Month i
        else Nothing
```

is exported, which will only return a value if the input value is between 1 & 12 inclusive.

Now, using `Language.Haskell.TH.Quote`, I have defined a quasi-quoting ... operator? ... that allows me to "create" instances of Month "at compile time":

```
month :: QuasiQuoter
month = QuasiQuoter { quoteDec  = error "quoteDec not implemented"
                    , quoteType = error "quoteType not implemented"
                    , quotePat  = "quotePat not implemented"
                    , quoteExp = (\ s → ⟦ force $ __fromString @Month s ⟧)
                    }


m :: Month
m = [month|3|]
```

Where `__fromString` parses a string, and either returns a value or calls `error`.  `force` is from `Control.DeepSeq`.

Now this is well and good, but the principle value of this is to catch bad values as early as possible - but, thanks to Lazy Evaluation, the value m is not evaluated either at compile-time (which would be ideal, but a rather tall order, perhaps) or at least at the earliest stage of runtime.

Is there any way that I can annotate the value (preferably within the quasi-quotation infra, so that every use of `month` gets it for free; but failing that, annotating `m`) to force the evaluation of `m` when the program gets run?  Requiring an `NFData` constraint or similar is fine.

Thanks,

Comment: You can force evaluation with bang patterns and `seq`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq

Comment: I suggest including the definition of `month` (and, for completeness `mon`) in your question.

Comment: `quoteExp month "3"` is definitely executed at compile-time, because that's what quasi-quotes do. If that action did the necessary checking, it would fail to compile.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I am familiar with BangPatterns & `seq`; but struggling to see how to apply them here.  To my understanding, they only apply when the encompassing value (the argument to `seq`, say) is evaluated.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr - fair point, added.

Comment: @Carl - that is also my understanding, but I am struggling to see how to make that help; e.g., the `s` in `quoteExp` in the code (newly added, above) even `force`ing the `__fromString` doesn`t help - the issue seems to be that the resulting divergence still isn't evaluated until runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your quasiquoter just defers everything to runtime by putting everything inside a quote. You need to move the parsing and verification outside the quote.

My quick proof of concept:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DeriveLift #-}
module A ( Month,
           mon,
           month
         ) where

import Text.Read
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax (Lift)
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote

newtype Month = Month Int deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Lift)

mon :: Int -> Maybe Month
mon n | n >= 1 && n <= 12 = Just $ Month n
      | otherwise = Nothing

monthExpImpl :: String -> Q Exp
monthExpImpl s = case readMaybe s of
  Nothing -> fail "Couldn't parse input as number"
  Just n -> case mon n of
    Nothing -> fail "Not a valid month"
    Just x -> [| x |]

month :: QuasiQuoter
month = QuasiQuoter { quoteDec  = error "quoteDec not implemented"
                    , quoteType = error "quoteType not implemented"
                    , quotePat  = error "quotePat not implemented"
                    , quoteExp = monthExpImpl
                    }
```

Note that `monthExpImpl` puts all the logic outside of the quote.  `fail` is the recommended way to terminate a `Q` action with a compilation error, strange as that feels to someone used to thinking of `fail` as a historical accident that we're moving away from.

The most surprising bits here are the `DeriveLift` extension and its use to add `Lift` to the list of derived classes for `Month`. [`Lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.15.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Lift) is used by TH to convert a value to code that generates that value. Without it, the compiler has no idea how to make the `[| x |]` quote into code.

You might wonder about how valid it is for TH to generate code that calls a constructor that shouldn't be visible from the compilation unit the generated code is in.  I wondered the same.  Turns out it's fine, as long as the code that creates the constructor in TH *can* see the constructor.  In this case, it's the `Lift` instance which is doing that, and it's defined in the same module, so it can see the constructor.  That might give you pause about creating such an instance, because you can't prevent an instance from being exported. And that's a valid consideration.  In this case it's fine, though, because `lift` requires a value to convert to code, and the only* way to get such a value from outside the module is through `mon` anyway, so it doesn't introduce any new ways to muck things up. (I say "only*" because `unsafeCoerce` exists, but let's just pretend it doesn't. When you use it, you have to take responsibility for breaking everything anyway.)

Comment: Well blow me down, it works.  Many thanks!  I'm going to have to stare at the `Lift` stuff for a little while to understand it, but it does indeed do what I asked.  Kudos, and gratitude.

Comment: @user3416536 Here's an analogy that might help with `Lift`: it's the template Haskell version of `Show`. It converts values to their AST, so they can be included in the rendered output merged into a splice.